# Wordpress Live copy & Xampp with different port

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, xampp

So there is this live wordpress-site and I have to make some new adjustments. Therefore I dumped the whole database and copied the files via FTP to my localhost (c:\xampp\htdocs\mycopy). 
However I run XAMPP on port 808 and the wp-copy can't deal with this.

```
http://localhost/mycopy/
```

404 - Not found

Tried it with

```
http://localhost:808/mycopy/
```

301 - moved permanently -> redirects to

```
http://localhost/mycopy/
```

and that gives again 404 not found.

Then I found the wp_options table in the database and set the "siteurl" and "home" both to

```
http://localhost:808/mycopy
```

Still no change...however I can open

```
http://localhost:808/xampp/splash.php
```

with my browser and it`s working like a charme.

Additional note:

```
http://localhost:808/mycopy/wp-admin/
```

redirects to www.livepage.de/wp-admin/

What did I miss?

Comment: have you edited wp-config.php?

Comment: Just found the file.

Original code is 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

and I tried it with
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:808');
but now the browser loads like forever...dratz.

Comment: the db_host should be localhost. Username 'root' and password blank. Take a look at this tutorial: https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-copy-of-a-live-wordpress-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the prob....and I am as dumb as a brick. httpd.conf has this line

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
```

and I changed it to 127.0.0.0.1:808

now take a wild guess what my problem was....But thx for your answers, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change links in database. WordPress stores full path links in the DB.

Set DB_HOST to "localhost:808" in wp_config.php

Then use this tool to replace urls in the database:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

just follow the instructions